# Xcode 11 - "Couldn't communicate with a helper application." when attempting to add Swift Package

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I am having problems when I attempt to add a new Swift Package to my project.

On Xcode 11.3.1 I receive a "Couldn't communicate with a helper application." error message.

PS with Xcode 11.4 the error message has changed to "Communication with the service was interrupted."

[image]

## Crash Report

Having looked in the console app I can see a `com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git` crash is occuring. I've uploaded the crash report here...

https://gist.github.com/OliverPearmain/0320f34d6381d1bb7900ff266fc8d703

Comment: I have the exact same problem. First, I thought Little Snitch blocks some outgoing connection related to Git but it wasn't the case.

Comment: I've signed in to my GitHub account in Xcode with a Personal access token. This way I can work around this issue by searching the library from the list but the original issue didn't go away.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I've finally worked out what this was.  I had something in my `~/.gitconfig` file which Xcode obviously did't like.

I worked this out by removing the `~/.gitconfig` and then retrying (and it worked).  Then I tried removing parts of the `~/.gitconfig` contents bit by bit.

Evntually I idenitified that this was the section causing the issue.

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/some/path/"]
    path = "~/some/path/.gitconfig_include"
```

This section works in other contexts.  No idea why it causes Xcode to barf.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that removing every includeIf config fixes the problem. Reported as FB7652466.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Just one more question though… How the hell did you get to this! x_x

Comment: Live saver! Also filed a bug (FB8951172)

Comment: Thanks! This is the reason!

Comment: Fired a radar 39442348

Comment: This issue still exists in Xcode 13 :(

Comment: awesome answer! And appreciated what you did!!!

Comment: This worked for me, and the bug still exists in Version 13.2.1 (13C100). I submitted an Xcode bug via Apple Feedback Assistant as well 

Comment: Such a shame this still exists in xcode 13! IncludeIf is so essential for my daily tasks. Anybody knows any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was caused by empty email line in ~/.gitconfig.

Changing "email = " to "email = example.email.com" helped.

Answer (score 1):

Had a stale entry in my `~/.gitconfig` with difftool set to an app that I don't have now.

Removed the entry, reopened Xcode, problem gone.