# Can't add Swift Package using File > Add Packages ... in Xcode 13 beta

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode13

I created a new iOS project and now I'm trying to add `Alamofire` as a dependency using Xcode (which uses Swift Package Manager under the hood, I suppose). However, it just doesn't work. When I enter `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git` in the search bar, it just doesn't find anything. My GitHub account is connected, but that shouldn't matter I guess.

Comment: I have a SwiftUI project and 13-beta and it imports just fine.

Comment: @RTXGamer Interesting. Using the same approach? The project is fresh. Created using Xcode 13 beta. I have literally touched nothing. Did you do the same or did you take any additional steps.

Comment: same steps, but it worked for me.

Comment: Interesting. I get `com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git quit unexpectedly.` when hitting enter on that URL in the search field. Fresh project.

Comment: And I am using beta 1 Xcode 13. Keep using stable 12.5.1, If you ain't experimenting with Xcode 13 features.

Comment: I'm experimenting with those features :)

Comment: @LuMa, did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: Not on a beta version. Haven't tried with RC/latest tbh. Will try and update this post.

Comment: Does not seem to work. "Communication with the service was interrupted" when trying to copy-paste the address in the search bar.

Comment: So the same thing happened to me @LuMa, I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61049144/11559619 apparently is an old known bug from Apple's side that has to do with your gitconfig if you use includeIf statements, I commented that and then it worked fine 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 11 - "Couldn't communicate with a helper application." when attempting to add Swift Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857372/xcode-11-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application-when-attempting-to)

Comment: Jesus. Yes! This is the issue. Oh my god. Can't believe it :D Feel free to create an answer I can mark as accepted :)